# Xamarin Forms: Debug and release options are only available for my project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am experiencing a weird problem with one of my projects. It has only Debug and Release options like the below screenshot:

[image]

Due to this, I can't run my app on physical iPhone devices. But for other projects, all the options are visible like the below screenshot.

[image]

I don't know why this is happening and any solutions for this issue? **My Mac VS version is 8.10.22.**

Comment: Make sure you add it into your Xcode devices first.

Comment: @MarkPW I am using visual studio, not xcode

Comment: you defined your configuration in Solution -> Properties -> Configuration

Comment: @Jason Only release and Debug is there https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttqXw.png

Comment: You can add more.  The configs are completely user-defined

Comment: @Jason Mainly I need the Debug | iPhone configuration, so what will be the name of that configuration?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you name it

Comment: @Jason Created a new configuration on solution. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwFPX.png But how we can add it for ios project?

Comment: please read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/understanding-build-configurations?view=vs-2022

Comment: @Jason Please post it as your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio build configurations are completely user defined.  See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/understanding-build-configurations?view=vs-2022)